# Ruby on Rails - Images not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following a tutorial to the dot, and my images are just not displaying.

The images are housed in the app/assets/images folder, with the .jpg extension.

The relevant code is:

index.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
<aside id="notice"><%= notice %></aside>
<% end %>

<h1>Products</h1>
  <table>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <%= link_to 'New product', new_product_path %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
        <td class="image">
          <%= image_tag image_url(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %>

        </td>
        <td class="description">
          <h1><%= product.title %></h1>
          <p>
            <%= truncate(strip_tags(product.description), length: 80) %>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td class="actions">
          <ul>
            <li><%= link_to 'Show', product %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <%= image_tag 'assets/7apps.jpg' %>
    <%= image_url 'assets/7apps.jpg' %
```

The last two pieces of code was just me experimenting with the different answers I have searched through Stack, and it just isn't working for me at all.
If it helps:

[image: Image folder]

[image: Website]

**Question**: What exactly have I done wrong where the images are not displaying?

**EDIT: Following Julien's help, the image is now appearing for the `<%= image_tag 'assets/7apps.jpg' %>` code.**

Also the code for the loop, which is from Julien:

```
<td class="image">
  <%= image_tag product.image_url, class: 'list_image' %>
</td>
```

Annoyingly, the images for the products table is still not working. I've attached an image.

[image: Website 2]

This is the database of the items:

```
Product.create!(title: 'Seven Mobile Apps in Seven Weeks',
  description:
    %{<p>
      <em>Native Apps, Multiple Platforms</em>
      Answer the question “Can we build this for ALL the devices?” with a
      resounding YES. This book will help you get there with a real-world
      introduction to seven platforms, whether you’re new to mobile or an
      experienced developer needing to expand your options. Plus, you’ll find
      out which cross-platform solution makes the most sense for your needs.
      </p>},
  image_url: '7apps.jpg',
  price: 26.00)
```

So I hope that makes sense, for the product.image_url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to include 'assets/' in the path:

```
<%= image_tag '7apps.jpg' %>
```

as for the products loop this should be enough, although i have no idea what `image_url` contains:

```
<%= image_tag product.image_url, class: 'list_image' %>
```

Comment: Hi Julien, thank you for that. I've updated my information now, explaining the image_url. Interestingly, the first part of the code works, but when I use the for loop code it's not working still.

Comment: check the source of the generated html for the missing images, what does the `src` attribute of the images look like?

Comment: Hi Julien, that's very interesting! I've checked the src attribute and this is it:

```<tr class="list_line_even">
        <td class="image">
          <img class="list_image" src="/assets/7apps-f67c3d908f537bac34a290206cc1db4c6f4611196c550e49ba836b796a2602bb.jpg" alt="7apps" />
        </td>```

So when I click the link the image does load in a seperate window, but it's still not appearing on the actual web page. What should I be doing here?

Comment: seems like the image is fine so i'm thinking the problem might be that the image is simply hidden, what is the CSS for the `list_image` class?

Comment: Hi Julien, so the .image CSS had a display: none; , which I have deleted and now the images are appearing! I had written that in there because the tutorial said to place in to "hide on mobile devices" but clearly this was not working. Thanks a lot for your help, you are a life saver